# Sata to usb c not recognized on ideapad gaming 3

Tags: hard-drive, usb, laptop, ssd, sata

A SATA to USB C cable meant for a 2.5 drive, plugged into a 2.5 SSD, and into my IdeaPad Gaming 3, isn't showing up. What am I doing wrong?

These are the SSD and cable I've got.

- [Benfei USB-C to SATA Adapter for 2.5" HDD/SSD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PGH1HX9)
- [Western Digital 1TB WD Blue 3D NAND Internal PC SSD - SATA III 6 Gb/s, 2.5"/7mm, Up to 560 MB/s - WDS100T2B0A](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073SBQMCX)

Comment: The cable you linked to is a SATA to Thunderbolt 3 cable.  Does your machine support Thunderbolt 3?

Comment: @Ramhound Nope. It is USB C from a sketchy brand that has that as the title but then lists in the specs, “FAST TRANSFER SPEEDS: USB 3.1 Gen 2 (5 Gbps) adapter cable with USB-C connector for 2.5” SATA drives” So they are trying to do a switcheroo on folks who want Thunderbolt 3 speeds but are cheap and just want to spend $10.99 on an item. For USB C, 5 Gbps is 100% fine. Always read the fine print!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The cable is compatible with the port.

Here's what to do.

- Go into your Services and make sure "Virtual Disk" is running.
- Open up Diskpart and type "automount"
- Restart PC

Then open up Disk Management, follow the prompt, then right click in the empty space for your new disk at the bottom of the window and select the option to create a new volume, follow the prompt, you're done!